# SQLalchemy mysql url connection string on cloud sql

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

What's the conncetion URL for mysql in sqlalchemy while connecting to google app engine ??

I know it's

```
mysql+gaerdbms:///<dbname>?instance=<my cloud instance name>
```

But where to specify user, password and host. I get below error while connecting with above string.

```
947, in MakeRequest raise _ToDbApiException(response.sql_exception) OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1045, u"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)") None None
```

Comment: BTW, [it is very bad idea to run your application as root](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/concern-about-logging-in-as-root-overrated)

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=appengine#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.gaerdbms

Comment: [It seems](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=appengine#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.gaerdbms) the new URL format is: `mysql+mysqldb://root@/<dbname>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<projectid>:<instancename>`

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql+gaerdbms://` is deprecated. Please use the `mysql+mysqldb://` instead. The format of the connection URI is:

`mysql+mysqldb://root@/<dbname>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<projectid>:<instancename>`

Note that the above only works in App Engine prod. The recommended way to connect from dev_appserver is to request an IP and use that to connect.

Reference: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=appengine#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.gaerdbms

Comment: Thanks Drew and Razvan. I tried follwowing format and it worked.

mysql+mysqldb://root:password@/<dbname>?unix_socket=/cloudsql/<projectid>:<instancename>